# storing a special character in mongodb using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bson, robo3t

I have a Json file which contains a list of jsons as below:

```
[{"name":"somename","value":{"$ne":"negativity"}}]
```

I am parsing or reading this file and dumping in the mongo like:

```
for file in os.listdir('/opt/myfiles/test.json'):
    with open(file, 'r') as fi:
        dict = json.load(fi)
        for data in dict:
            db.collection.insert(data)
```

It throws an error which is :

```
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: key '$ne' must not start with '$'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of $ in field names is not supported by drivers. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#field-names.

Per the rules given there you should be able to insert your document into the server since $ne isn't a top-level field, provided you find a driver that would allow you to do this (pymongo apparently not being one of them).

Comment: Is the newer version is better?